# How can I get latexmk to work with pandoc?

Tags: pdftex, pandoc, latexmk

## Problem and context

I have a shell script that downloads markdown files from a Gitlab wiki, does some pandoc filtering and then converts it to a PDF.

The conversion to PDF happens with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), which uses LaTeX in the background. For some reason when I specify `latexmk` in the [`--pdf-engine`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--pdf-engine) option the script fails.

### Command and error

If I run `pandoc mwe.tex --pdf-engine=latexmk -o ./mwe.pdf` the process fails and `pdflatex.log` shows:

```
INFO  pdflatex - this process (2200) started by 'sh' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -recorder -output-directory=C://Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8 C://Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8/input.tex
INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
INFO  pdflatex - setting output directory: C:/Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8
INFO  pdflatex - setting aux directory: C:/Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8
ERROR pdflatex.core - Access is denied.

ERROR pdflatex.core - Function: FindFirstFileExW
ERROR pdflatex.core - Result: 5
ERROR pdflatex.core - Data: directory="C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18"
ERROR pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\DirectoryLister\win\winDirectoryLister.cpp:135
FATAL pdflatex - Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

FATAL pdflatex - Info: directory="C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18"
FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\DirectoryLister\win\winDirectoryLister.cpp
FATAL pdflatex - Line: 135
INFO  pdflatex - this process (2200) finishes with exit code 1
WARN  miktex.core - still open: C://Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8/input.tex
WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:/Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tex2pdf.-f71f6aebf5dc3db8\input.log
```

### What I've tried

Running `latexmk -pdf mwe.tex` works as expected.
Running `pandoc mwe.tex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o ./mwe.pdf` works as expected.

[This previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture) mentions that permissions should be set correctly. I've checked, and my user has `Full Control` permissions on `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\` and `c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\` folders.
However, the error states that the folder `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` is causing trouble, which only has permissions for the SYSTEM user.
That raises the question: why does pdflatex wants to access the SYSTEM recycle bin instead of my users recycle bin?

## MWE

My MWE is found below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Month 00, 1984}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some content

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be `pandoc mwe.md -o .mwe.tex; latexmk -pdf mwe.tex`  ?

Comment: I have some experience with `biber` misbehaving similarly when used in user-controlled windows environment. `latexmk` and `biber` are both perl (but the similarity ends there). Try to work as suggested by @Fran ; othewise you would have to do some changes for `par-packer` if you really insist on one step process with `latexmk`

Comment: The suggested workaround (first pandoc, then latexmk) works, but I'm still curious why it's not working. I'll see if I can post this at the pandoc forum.

Comment: "I've checked and my user has appropriate permissions. " However, it seems a problem of Windows permissions. In Linux I tested an equivalent markdown example, i.e., a `mwe.md` with a YALM header with title: xxx,  author: yyy,  date: date: zzz and output:  pdf_document,   and  only "Some content " as document text, and `pandoc --pdf-engine=latexmk  mwe.md -o mwe.pdf` works without any problem.

Comment: I've rechecked permissions, and indeed the folder it's complaining about (`C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18`) is not accessible to my user, but [that is at it should be](https://superuser.com/a/1335366/141595). Not sure why pdflatex wants to access it though.

Comment: You may want to pass a different directory to latexmk to use as a using [pdf-engine-opt](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--pdf-engine-opt) and the `-output-directory=dir` (or `-outdir=dir`) option of latemk. That is, try with `pandoc test.tex --pdf-engine=latexmk --pdf-engine-opt=-output-directory=. -o mwe.pdf`.