# Pandoc with --citeproc ignores \cite commands

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

In short: is there any way to use [`citeproc`](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc) with "pure" LaTeX bibliographical commands?

Longer version: in the following markdown file, the `[@Test]` "native" pandoc command is processed properly, but not the `\cite{Test}` command.

```
---
references:
- type: article-journal
  id: Test
  author:
  - family: Doe
    given: Joe 
  title: 'My paper'
---

[@Test]

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
For some reason, I need to switch to \LaTeX{} at some point.
For most \LaTeX{} commands it's fine, but not for \cite{Test}.
\end{minipage}
```

When compiled with

```
pandoc test.md --citeproc -o test.pdf
```

I get

[image]

Now, what really puzzles me is that pandoc is fine processing most (all?) of the LaTeX commands I can throw in my md file, *except* for the `\cite` command.

I am aware that I could use

```
pandoc test.md --biblatex -o test.tex
```

and then compile the tex file into a pdf, but I want to make sure first that I am not overlooking something obvious.

This question is somewhat similar to [*How to use pandoc-citeproc in raw latex block of a markdown document?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276351/34551), but goes the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [have asked](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/iaI_1KvtEuQ/m/Ux9xQXSeCQAJ) this question on [the pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/) list, and  [John MacFarlane](https://github.com/jgm)  confirmed that it was not possible:

> There isn't really a good way to do this, no.

The best ways to achieve something similar is to use

```
pandoc test.md -t latex -s --biblatex -o test.tex
pdflatex test
biber test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

Or, easier

```
pandoc test.md --biblatex -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=latexmk
```