# Change language when citing page ('s. 1' instead of 'p. 1')

Tags: citing, languages

I'm trying to change the language of in-text-citations. I'm using pandoc to convert my files from markdown (using obsidian with 'pandoc-plugin') so my citations usually look like this [@citekey] (this may also mean my problems are pandoc- or obsidian-related, so please let me know). When I write in english, latex has no problem with citations of specific pages: [@citekey, p. 1] gives 'author, year, p. 1'. However, when I write in norwegian, it leaves out the norwegian version of 'p.': [@citekey, s. 1], which gives me, 'author, year, 1', instead of 'author, year, s. 1'.

bibfile:

```
@article{auth_2020,
  title = {title},
  author = {auth},
  data = {2020}
}
```

For example for the md file:

```
---
lang: nb
---
he said this [@auth_2020, s. 1]
```

and the pandoc command:

```
pandoc --from markdown --to pdf -o C:\Users\pandoctopdf --pdf-engine=xelatex C:\Users\pandocmd --metadata bibliography=C:\pathtobib --citeproc -csl C:\pathtocsl
```

gives
"he said this (auth, 2020, 1)" and not "he said this (auth, 2020, s. 1)". When using

```
---
lang: nb
---
he said this [@auth_2020, p. 1]
```

I get "he said this (auth, 2020, p. 1)"

It does, however, when citing 2 authors change from 'author and author' to the norwegian version; 'author *og* author'

Thank you

Comment: 'Using Pandoc' does not really specify which file format your documents are written in, I assume some kind of Markdown or reStructuredText or something, maybe with citeproc to handle the references? It would be helpful if you can be more specific. Also providing the code for a full example document that can be compiled and shows the problem would help making your question easier to answer, including the exact commands that you use for compiling.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620478/pandoc-with-citeproc-ignores-cite-commands for an example of a question that has a clear reproducible example using Pandoc.

Comment: This is a bit better but not complete yet. You should provide a complete `.md` document, a `.bib` file, and a terminal command, such that when we run that command on that file it should run and give the wrong _author, year, 1_ output. Anything less than that means extra work for people that try to answer and guessing what you do exactly, and if they guess wrong then the answer is not useful for you.